# Selecting column from database table and renaming them in java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I am trying to display some field of my database on a java front end using eclipse.

I have manage to display the entire table but **I would like to do is to select some field of my database table as well as rename the field on my front end.**

*for example if there is a table called user with the fields(attributes) Name, age, height, weight,role. I would like my front end to display a table with two column Name and Role*.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the columns that you don't want to see. Something like:

```
table.removeColumn( table.getColumn( "Weight" ) );
```

Or

```
TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
TableColumn tc = table.getColumn(3); // for the weight column
tcm.removeColumn( tc );
```

Comment: thanks but I am looking for a way by me passing an sql query to replace "select * from RQ"in my createable() method. I have tried to replace it with "select 'Name', 'Role' from RQ" but I end up with duplicate column header and no data displayed.